# Как построить uml диаграмму класса

Tags: uml, c++

Здравствуйте, мне по информатике в одной лабе дополнительно нужно нарисовать uml диаграмму класса.
На лекции не хожу, поэтому незнаю как да что. Погуглил, нашел программку которая якобы по исходному коду может это сделать (ArgoUML). Но запустив данную программу, я не могу ни с чем разобраться. Собственно хотелось узнать каким способом сейчас быстро могу сделать ее?

Спасибо.

Comment: > На лекции не хожу

:)

Comment: зато правда)

Comment: фигово это у тебя получается... гугли юмл основы, вся ночь впереди

Comment: ну почему так сразу, просто мне эти юмл как то не очень охото изучать (я имею ввиду прям изучать, то есть прочитать немало текста)

это важная вещь в программировании?

Comment: по поводу важности: это больше для архитектора имеет значение, нежели для программиста. да и то, все относительно. на западе где-то пользуется спросом в больших проектах.

Comment: ну вот и я думаю, сделать по быстому и не заморачиваться)
у меня класс то простой: 4 свойства(приватные), в паблике конструктор деструктор и 5 методов

Comment: ручкой на листе, в пейнте, в ворде(можно заюзать таблицы), visio
не говоря уже о Rational Rose от IBM :)

Comment: да проблема то не в этом) я от руки нарисую, но я просто незнаю как он выглядит, я ниже под первым ответом спросил : так ли эта диаграмма выглядит как по ссылке что я привел

Comment: да, так и выглядит, как по ссылке что ты привел.

Comment: А что "рациональная рожа" уже от IBM, а не от Rational? А насчёт использования, в одном форуме:

    -- А насколько UML используются в реальных проектах?

    -- Это зависит от степени деградации нервных клеток головного мозга.

Comment: Ага, вот такие стюденты. А потом министр связи сообщает, что у нас не хватает IT-специалистов и будем их из Китая выписывать. Блин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитай, тут отлично расписано: [Диаграммы классов UML.](http://www.informicus.ru/default.aspx?SECTION=6&id=73&subdivisionid=3)

Comment: спасибо, этой одной страницы достаточно для проделки моего задания?

Comment: а случайно не это вот изображение http://www.informicus.ru/Picture.aspx?id=55 есть диаграмма класса?

Comment: кстати, если юзаеш студию - она умеет делать юмл по проекту

Comment: да, слышал, но не юзаю идэшки)
может ты юзаешь и сделаешь? пожалуйста конечно)

Comment: у тебя всего один класс? т.к. диаграмма называется диаграммой класс**ов**
[ссылка на wiki][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: да ,  один

Comment: Диаграмма классов строится на основе хотя бы нескольких классов.
Бессмысленно мутить для одного класса...

Comment: Уверен, что тебе нужно только с одним классом работать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот программа - сама строит диаграммы состояний, класса и так далее. Так же есть возможность экспорта кода в Java, ну а так как формат UML поддерживают и другие програмы, то потом просто найдешь программу, которая переводит UML в С++ код и так далее.

WIKI: [ссылка на Wiki](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRational_Software&ei=mWKSUPDSHqr34QTtx4GwDw&usg=AFQjCNGuZWfjQvKsH91GC-lwYsJf1qC8gg&sig2=UW9SCbPOl3nKptz85Herpg)

Программа [ссылка на программу](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/rose/)